# Laravel validation - fail when provided with input not defined in rules

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Does Laravel validation provide any ways to fail when request contains input keys that are *not* defined in validation rules? Ex: `Validator` is instantiated with the following rules: `['name' => 'required', 'email' => 'required|email']`. I want validation to fail if `$request` contains *any* other keys except `name` and `email` (Think of a user POSTing to the route end-point with undesirable data). Is that possible to achieve with simple validation rules?

P.S. I am aware of mass-assignment tricks with Eloquent, however I need to perform strict validation before any data is manipulated / persisted.

Comment: Why would you be worried about other keys? Don't use `->all()` with `->fill()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to achieve with simple validation rules but would be easy to add.

All you would need to do is something like the following...

```
if ( count(request()->except(['name', 'email']) ) > 0) {
    return false;
}
```